# I can't make a menu bar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to build menubar like this video ('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PUZ8LrWFWc') But it's not working. I tried pressing on menu button but nothing happened. I tried moving the button code and wrap it with Row and used GestureDetector and build a button in it like in the video but nothing happened.

this's code before did like the video

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<String> imageList = [
    //image data
    'https://www.matichon.co.th/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/บิ๊กป้อมพักสายตาประชุมสภา.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/d8/ac/3a/d8ac3ad182334ba859ceb9f70f3a64fd.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/e5/4c/06/e54c060156c18cc776b4e15da2d6d035.jpg',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(          
   
      home: Scaffold(
 
        appBar: AppBar(       
          backgroundColor:
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 96, 148, 44), 
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment:
                MainAxisAlignment.center, 
            children: [
              Image.network(
       
                'http://www.srv.ac.th/home/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/sara-logo.png', 
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
               
                height: 55, 
                errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Icon(Icons.hide_image_outlined), 
              ),
              Container(         
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),    
              )
            ],
          ),
          leading: (IconButton( 
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu_outlined),
            onPressed: () {},  
          )),
        ),
        body: Container(  
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30), 
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[  
            CarouselSlider(     
              options: CarouselOptions(  
                enlargeCenterPage: true,  
                enableInfiniteScroll: true,  
                autoPlay: true,  
              ),
              items: imageList.map((e) => ClipRRect(  
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),  
                        child: Stack( 
                          fit: StackFit.expand,  
                          children: <Widget>[  
                            Image.network(  
                              e, 
                              width: 1050,  
                              height: 350,  
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,  
                              errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => 
                                  const Icon(Icons.hide_image_outlined),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
            const Divider(
              height: 40,
              thickness: 2,
              indent: 20,
              endIndent: 20,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 20),
                child: const Text('ข่าวประชาสัมพันธ์',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 135),
                  child: const Text('เรียงตามวันที่',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                )],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 2),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.sort_outlined,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my code after tried did it like video

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {


  final List<String> imageList = [
    //image data
    'https://www.matichon.co.th/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/บิ๊กป้อมพักสายตาประชุมสภา.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/d8/ac/3a/d8ac3ad182334ba859ceb9f70f3a64fd.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/e5/4c/06/e54c060156c18cc776b4e15da2d6d035.jpg',
  ];

  double xOffset = 0;
  double yOffset = 0;

  bool isDrawerOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return MaterialApp(       
   
      home: Scaffold(
       
        appBar: AppBar(     
          backgroundColor:
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 96, 148, 44), 
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment:
                MainAxisAlignment.center, 
            children: [
              Image.network(
               
                'http://www.srv.ac.th/home/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/sara-logo.png', 
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                
                height: 55, 
                errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Icon(Icons.hide_image_outlined), 
              ),
              Container(         
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),    
              )
            ],
          ),
          leading: (IconButton(         
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                xOffset = 290;
                yOffset = 80;
                isDrawerOpen = true;
              });
            },               
          )),
        ),
        body: Container(     
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30), 
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[  
            CarouselSlider(   
              options: CarouselOptions( 
                enlargeCenterPage: true,  
                enableInfiniteScroll: true, 
                autoPlay: true,  
              ),
              items: imageList.map((e) => ClipRRect( 
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), 
                        child: Stack( 
                          fit: StackFit.expand, 
                          children: <Widget>[ 
                            Image.network(  
                              e,  
                              width: 1050,  
                              height: 350,  
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,  
                              errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>  
                                  const Icon(Icons.hide_image_outlined), 
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
            const Divider(
              height: 40,
              thickness: 2,
              indent: 20,
              endIndent: 20,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 20),
                child: const Text('ข่าวประชาสัมพันธ์',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 135),
                  child: const Text('เรียงตามวันที่',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                )],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 2),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.sort_outlined,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      )
    );
  }

  Widget buildMenu(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(xOffset, yOffset, 0)
        ..scale(isDrawerOpen ? 0.85 : 1.00)
        ..rotateZ(isDrawerOpen ? -50 : 0),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
  }
}
```

Previews
[image: This is my HomeScreen]

Comment: did you check the source code of the video?

Comment: Yes,I tried applying his code to my project but it didn't work.